# Choosing between buying and selling

Tags: usability, categorization

What is the best approach to showing the difference between wanting to buy and having an item for sale? These options come to mind:

1. A filter or sorting menu like list view and thumbnail view;
2. Tabs for 'Item for sale' and 'Want to buy';
3. A dropdown menu for choosing between categories.

Any suggestions for how I can improve the usability of this? I'm planning to do some A/B testing but I wanted to ask here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest any out of the following approaches

- Filter: [all][buy][sale]
- Tabular: | Buy | Sale |

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and  think i will make an a/b testing for this